# How to pass value of state in a function in react using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I've been working on a project. I want to pass the value of the state to the functions as a parameter or maybe my understanding is wrong. I created a function called  resetArray. Where I'm creating the array of random values and setting the state of the array. Now I want that array to pass as a parameter to the mergeSort function to sort the array but I don't think my approach is correct.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react'
import './Randomarray.css'

export default function RandomArrayJanrator() {

    const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        resetArray();
    }, [])

    const resetArray = () => {
        const array = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 310; i++) {
            //array.push(Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 10) - 10)));
            array.push(randomIntFromInterval(5, 750));
            setArray(array);
        }
    }
    function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }


    function mergeSort(array) //trying to pass state here as a perameter
       {
        if (array.length === 1) return array;
        const middle = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
        const firstHalf = mergeSort(array.slice(0, middle));
        const secondHalf = mergeSort(array.slice(middle));

        const sortedArray = [];

        let i = 0, j = 0;

        while (i < firstHalf.length && j < secondHalf.length) {
            if (firstHalf[i] < secondHalf[j]) {
                sortedArray.push(firstHalf[i++])
            }
            else {
                sortedArray.push(secondHalf[j++]);
            }
        }

        while (i < firstHalf.length) sortedArray.push(firstHalf[i]);
        while (j < secondHalf.length) sortedArray.push(secondHalf[j]);
        return sortedArray;

    }


    return (
        <>
            <div className='container'>
                {array.map((value, indx) => (
                    <div className='array-bar' key={indx} style={{ height: `${value}px`, color: '#fff', fontSize: '2px' }}>{value}</div>
                ))}

            </div>
            <button onClick={() => resetArray()}>Array Genrator</button>
            <button onClick={() => mergeSort()}>Merge Sort</button>
        </>

    )
}
```

[image: Error on running merge sort]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try this `<button onClick={() => mergeSort(array)}>Merge Sort</button>`

Comment: Yes, but getting the same error.

Comment: Use `setArray(array);` outside `for` loop and check. Also check if `firstHalf ` and `secondHalf` data is of type array

Comment: Just call ```const sorted = mergeSort(array)``` after ```resetArray``` with ```array``` state  and then ```setState(sorted)```

Comment: Done!!!.  firstHalf and secondHalf are type object which is array.    Also passing array to onclick breaking the code. Added snippet

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a problem in your algorith causing an infinite loop, here:

```
 while (i < firstHalf.length) sortedArray.push(firstHalf[i]);
 while (j < secondHalf.length) sortedArray.push(secondHalf[j]);
```

You forgot to increment `i` and `j`.

About your question, i solved it by having a `mergeSort` function that calls an helper function and then set the state with the sorted array. Here's the code with some comments:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import './Randomarray.css'

export default function RandomArrayJanrator() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    resetArray();
  }, []);

  const resetArray = () => {
    const array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 310; i++) {
      array.push(randomIntFromInterval(5, 750));
    }
    // You can move this out of your loop
    setArray(array);
  };

  function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

  // You can define a function that sort the array using merge sort
  // and then set the state
  function mergeSort() {
    const sorted = mergeSortHelper(array);
    setArray(sorted);
  }

  // This is an helper function that works correctly with recursion
  function mergeSortHelper(array) {
    if (array.length <= 1) return array;
    const middle = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    const firstHalf = mergeSortHelper(array.slice(0, middle));
    const secondHalf = mergeSortHelper(array.slice(middle));

    const sortedArray = [];

    let i = 0,
      j = 0;

    while (i < firstHalf.length && j < secondHalf.length) {
      if (firstHalf[i] < secondHalf[j]) {
        sortedArray.push(firstHalf[i++]);
      } else {
        sortedArray.push(secondHalf[j++]);
      }
    }

    // You forgot to increment you counters here causing an infinite loop
    while (i < firstHalf.length) sortedArray.push(firstHalf[i++]);
    while (j < secondHalf.length) sortedArray.push(secondHalf[j++]);
    return sortedArray;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        {array.map((value, indx) => (
          
          //removed the styles temporarely because i couldn't read results
          <div className="array-bar" key={indx}>
            {value}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => resetArray()}>Array Genrator</button>

      <button onClick={() => mergeSort()}>Merge Sort</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2ueaft?file=src%2FRandomArrayJanrator.js

Comment: HEy, Thanks for the help. But It didn't work out.  Getting Maximum stack limit hit at line             --------const firstHalf = mergeSort(array.slice(0, middle));

Comment: did you check all the changes? that line has changed now and it call the helper function instead: `const firstHalf = mergeSortHelper(array.slice(0, middle));`

Comment: Ah....sorry miss that part. Thanks  alot for the help!!!